# Limit of sequence $x_n = x_{n-1} \cdot(2-\frac{\tan^{-1}(n) \cdot n^2 - 3}{3 + n^2})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Find limit of a sequence:
$$x_n = \left(2-\frac{\tan^{-1}(1) \cdot 1^2 - 3}{3 + 1^2}\right)\left(2-\frac{\tan^{-1}(2) \cdot 2^2 - 3}{3 + 2^2}\right) \cdot \ldots \cdot \left(2-\frac{\tan^{-1}(n) \cdot n^2 - 3}{3 + n^2}\right)$$

Recursively:
$x_n = x_{n-1} \cdot \left(2-\frac{\tan^{-1}(n) \cdot n^2 - 3}{3 + n^2}\right)$.
I think that for big enough $n$, expression in the parentheses becomes smaller than $1$, so $(x_n)$ should be decreasing.
And after I move on to limit in recurrence formula, I get that limit is $0$. Is this right ?

Comment: That the factors are eventually smaller than $1$ is not enough and only shows that $x_n$ is decreasing. However, the *limit* of the factors is $2-\frac \pi2$, so $<1$, and that implies $x_n\to 0$.

Comment: Yes, but from the fact that $x_n$ is decreasing and bounded below, by zero, it follows that it converges ?
And if limit of $x_n$ is $a$, from $a = a \times\left(2-\frac{arctg(n) \times n^2 - 3}{3 + n^2}\right)$, it follows that $a$ is zero. Is this reasoning ok ?

Answer (score 1):

For $n$ large enough $\arctan(n)\in (\pi/2-0.1,\pi/2)$, let $d=\pi/2-0.1$, then $\arctan(n)>d$ for $n$ large enough. Some algebra gives
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
2-\frac{\arctan(n) n^2-3}{3+n^2}&\leqslant \frac{2-d}{1+\frac{3}{n^2}}\\
&\leqslant 2-d+0.1\text{ for }n \text{ large enough}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
This means that for $n$ large enough we are multiplying by a number less than 0.63, and hence will give zero.